# Making 2 columns distinct

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-visualization

I want to increase the count of 4 different variables to fill in a pie chart. But i only want it to increment the variables per unique variable in the 2 columns. I want to try to make them distinct but i do not quite understand how to. In the if statement i try to compare the value with a string. This works. After the || i try to make it distinct but i have trouble with that.

Here is my code:

```
        function createPiechartthree(){
        var columns = {};
        var xmlColumns = $j('head', xml);
        xmlColumns.find('headColumn').each(function(){

        var columnName = $j(this).find('columnValue').text();
        var columnID = $j(this).attr('columnid');
        columns[columnName] = (columnID);
    });

        var xmlData = $j('data', xml);

        xmlData.find('item').each(function(){
        $j(this).find('column').each(function(){
            var colID = $j(this).attr("columnid");


        console.log(colID);
            var value = $j(this).find('displayData').text();



        if(colID == columns["Risk level client"] || colID == columns["Counterparty name"] ){
            if(value === "High" || value === value){
                highRiskCategory++;
            }
            else if(value === "Medium" || value === value){
                mediumRiskCategory++;
            }
            else if(value === "Low" || value === value){
                lowRiskCategory++;
            } else if(value === "" || value === value) {
                unidentified++;
            }




        }
        })
    })
```

Comment: The HTML and CSS is kinda huge.... but im trying to make a piechart with distinct values. I only need to get the var value distinct and/or unique.

Comment: The column "Risk level client" contains 4 values called  "High"  "Medium" , "Low"  and ""  if it is left empty (it's a drop down choice menu). The other one "Counterparty name"  is a single text line. Now i want to make a piechart with 4 values (the variables riskCategory and unidentified) and the amount of counterparty's in the piechart. Example: ( High, 2). 2 Counterparty's are a high risk level client. But Counterparty's make transactions so they are registered more then 1 time. This increments the piechart as well and i don't want that. Thats why i want to make Counterparty's distinct

Comment: It's like this:                                                                                                                 Starbucks  high,                                                                                                 Starbucks  high ,                                                                                                 McDonalds low                                                                                                  now what happens in the piechart is: high, 2 low, 1                                             Starbucks has been counted 2 times.

Comment: i want to count Starbucks 1 time. this is how the piechart is being filled:     var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
       ['Risk level client', 'Amount'],
       ['Very low', 0],
       ['Low', lowRiskCategory],
       ['Medium', mediumRiskCategory],
       ['High', highRiskCategory],
       ['unidentified',  unidentified]
     ]);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) rather than incrementing the counts manually, build an array of the values found...

```
var riskData = [
  ['Starbucks', 'High'],
  ['Starbucks', 'High'],
  ['McDonalds', 'Low'],
  ['Dunkin', 'Medium'],
  ['Dunkin', 'Medium'],
  ['Dunkin', 'Medium'],
  ['Subway', 'Low'],
  ['Chick-fil-a', ''],
  ['Chick-fil-a', '']
];
```

2) then filter out the duplicates...

```
var pieData = new google.visualization.DataTable();
pieData.addColumn('string', 'Risk Level');

var counterParty = [];
riskData.forEach(function (riskLevel) {
  if (counterParty.indexOf(riskLevel[0]) === -1) {
    counterParty.push(riskLevel[0]);
    var rowData = (riskLevel[1] === '') ? ['Unidentified'] : [riskLevel[1]];
    pieData.addRow(rowData);
  }
});
```

3) then use google's `group` method to aggregate the counts...

```
var groupPie = google.visualization.data.group(
  pieData,
  [0],
  [{
    aggregation: google.visualization.data.count,
    column: 0,
    label: 'Count',
    type: 'number'
  }]
);
```

---

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages: ['controls']
});

function drawChart() {
  // create array like this
  var riskData = [
    ['Starbucks', 'High'],
    ['Starbucks', 'High'],
    ['McDonalds', 'Low'],
    ['Dunkin', 'Medium'],
    ['Dunkin', 'Medium'],
    ['Dunkin', 'Medium'],
    ['Subway', 'Low'],
    ['Chick-fil-a', ''],
    ['Chick-fil-a', '']
  ];

  // for example only <--
  var tableRisk = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    chartType: 'Table',
    containerId: 'table_risk',
    dataTable: google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(riskData, true)
  });
  tableRisk.draw();
  // -->

  var pieData = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  pieData.addColumn('string', 'Risk Level');

  var counterParty = [];
  riskData.forEach(function (riskLevel) {
    if (counterParty.indexOf(riskLevel[0]) === -1) {
      counterParty.push(riskLevel[0]);
      var rowData = (riskLevel[1] === '') ? ['Unidentified'] : [riskLevel[1]];
      pieData.addRow(rowData);
    }
  });

  // for example only <--
  var tablePie = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    chartType: 'Table',
    containerId: 'table_pie',
    dataTable: pieData
  });
  tablePie.draw();
  // -->

  var groupPie = google.visualization.data.group(
    pieData,
    [0],
    [{
      aggregation: google.visualization.data.count,
      column: 0,
      label: 'Count',
      type: 'number'
    }]
  );

  // for example only <--
  var tablePie = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    chartType: 'Table',
    containerId: 'table_group',
    dataTable: groupPie
  });
  tablePie.draw();
  // -->

  var chartPie = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    chartType: 'PieChart',
    containerId: 'chart_pie',
    dataTable: groupPie,
    options: {
      colors: ['red', 'orange', 'green', 'blue']
    }
  });
  chartPie.draw();
}
```

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 8px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="table_risk"></div>
<div id="table_pie"></div>
<div id="table_group"></div>
<div id="chart_pie"></div>
```